# JMX Enablement Error No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I am new to JMX and tried setting up the Enabling remote JMX with password authentication only.
I made the password jmxremote.password file and tried using the following command to make change the permissions on the password file to be readable only by the user who starts the server:

> cacls jmxremote.password /P username:R

But I got the following error :

***No mapping between account names and security IDs was done***

Thanks for the help community.